# On change select box option event is slow

Tags: jquery

Am having a drop-down with the class name `user_status`.

On the change event of this seletion, there is a dialog popup is coming.
Here is the code.

```
$('.user_status').change(function(){
    $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
        title     : 'Change Status',
        resizable : false,
        width     : 250,
        height    : 120,
        modal     : true,
        buttons   : {
            'Yes': function() {
                dialog_obj.dialog('close');
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    }); 
});
```

My problem is Its very slow(may take 3 or 4 seconds) to come this popup on the change event. How Can I fast this popup on change event?

Comment: What browser and what processor are you using? How much RAM do you have? If there's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), we can try it out and let you know how much time it takes. :)

Answer (score 1):

define your dialog before and just open the jquery dialog on event like this (untested code):

```
var jDialog =  $('#dialog-confirm').dialog({
        title     : 'Change Status',
        resizable : false,
        width     : 250,
        height    : 120,
        modal     : true,
        autoOpen  : false,
        buttons   : {
            'Yes': function() {
                dialog_obj.dialog('close');
            },
            'No': function() {
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    }); 
$('.user_status').change(function(){
   jDialog.dialog('open');
});
```